# CORS policy Error in react app while Zoho meeting api integrations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, oauth-2.0

I have been trying to integrate zoho meetings with my application(React is front end and django is backend).

While fetching the access token i'm getting the following error.

```html
Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?code=1000.53axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2e8e5eb43cfe53005f8d93490&client_id=1000.PGPL8RK7R54UR7JSNKTM2ZRETSF4CI&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/app_store/zoho_meet&grant_type=authorization_code' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

here is my axios code part`

```js
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      } 
})

const url = `https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?code=${zcode}&client_id=1000.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI&client_secret=92821f12d14cf11162891xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/app_store/zoho_meet&grant_type=authorization_code`
publicAxios.get(url)
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
})
 .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
})
```

`
can anybody here help me what steps did i missed here

Comment: Cors response headers are in responses. Stop using it in requests. Fix the server if it's yours. If it's not then you can't fix cors

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to Zoho API's from my React app using Netlify's serverless functions.(AWS Lambda functions under the hood)
I make all Api calls via serverless functions.
Api calls to Zoho fails with CORS error when run in the browser (client side). It HAS to run on a server.
One can also use Google functions, but I have not tried it.
Netlify documentation is great.

Comment: The browser does an OPTIONS call first, checking if you're allowed to make the call or not. The server doesn't, and therefore doesn't care

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).